# iphone startMonitoringRegion monitoredRegions size limit

Tags: iphone, monitor, cllocationmanager

is there a limit to the number of regions we can monitor?
monitoredRegions is a NSSet, but no specs on a hard limit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to find a specific number from Apple for number of regions you can monitor at once. The documentation says that your regions may get pushed out if it needs to make room for newer more current regions. All regions being monitored go into one pool for the OS, so 10 from you, 10 from another app... it's all the same.

If you want to ensure your regions are still active, you can pull in all the regions for your app using -monitoredRegions and loop through them. If you are missing one, add it back in. Good question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill. I played around with the Regions sample app available from apple, and it seems that the magic number is 10 as you pointed it out. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I know they all go into the same pool. I don't know what the actual cap is, but I know that everyone has to share.